# Is it possible to apply for Ph. D. program in Physics with a CS background?

Tags: phd, computer-science, engineering, physics

Currently i am doing BE in cs. Is it possible to apply for a graduate program in theoretical physics without having a bachelor's degree in physics or mathematics?

Comment: Would you please clarify  **what made you think you cannot** apply for  theoretical physics PhD program?

Comment: How much time did you spend studying calculus, especially differential equations? Physics, other than electricity? Those questions may not affect whether you can apply. They may affect whether you will be accepted. They will certainly affect whether you would succeed if accepted.

Comment: Question is closed so I can't answer. Yes, you can, and yes, you might be successful, even if it's much more likely you'll flounder. A good way to find out is take the 4 practice Physics GREs and see how you do. If you get a solid score, you're probably capable of catching up to other students in the program.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's possible. It depends on the country. If you live in one of the members of the UE, it is- this is the so called Bologna Process.

But another question is whether you should do it and I strongly advise you not to. You need strong knowledge of Maths and Physics. I highly doubt you will be able to catch up with that. Even if you do, it will take up a major part of your PhD and you won't have time for real work.

Comment: "But another question is whether you should do it and I strongly advise you not to. You need strong knowledge of Maths and Physics." I agree with the second sentence, but how do you know the OP doesn't have this strong knowledge?  Some people have this knowledge independently of what their degree program is...and CS is closely related to physics and (especially) math.

Comment: At my department, I know of 2 guys who changed direction in the sense that they have a BSc in CS, and at MSc they have switched to physics. In order to pursue an MSc, there was two entrance exams, one  in quantum mechanics and the other in classical electrodynamics. I have to say that these two guys have obtained the higher scores at these exams and obtained also a small fellowship, and they continued with the PhD.